# Is the empty set considered a down-set?

Tags: order-theory

This is a pedantic terminology question for a paper I'm writing.

Given a partial order $P$, a subset $U\subseteq P$ is called a down-set (also lower set, order ideal and several other names) if for every $s\in U$ and every $t\le s$ we have $t\in U$.

The empty set satisfies this condition vacuously, but I'm wondering whether there's any general consensus on whether the empty set should be considered a down-set. I consulted Wikipedia and a couple of text-books, but they didn't seem to mention this edge case.

Comment: Would you like the intersection of two down-sets to be a down-set?

Comment: If I think about ordinals, I'd say that the elements of $\alpha$ are the proper down-sets of $\alpha$, and I'm ok with $\emptyset$ being there when $\alpha\ne \emptyset$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng that's a good enough reason for me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, the emptyset satisfies the definition. It doesn't matter whether it satisfies it vacuously - that makes it a downset. I think the reason you're not seeing it explicitly addressed is that it isn't considered an edge case in the first place.

(Of course, there may be some results which hold only for *nonempty* down sets, so it could indeed form an edge case for the results you're looking at, but that doesn't affect the downset-ness of the emptyset.)

Comment: I should have clarified, it's an edge case in the specific thing I'm writing up, not necessarily in general. Angina Seng's comment convinced me that the empty set has to be included in any reasonable definition, so I will just write "we consider non-empty down-sets."